# Defining a variable - MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I have this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView contactNames;
        ....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        contactNames = findViewById(R.id.contact_names);
                ...
        }
}
```

The following is not clear to me:

1. Why do I get an error when i try to assign `contactNames` under `MainActivity`?
2. Why is it so important to find views after `setContentView` because if I find views before (under `onCreate`) I also get an error?

Comment: Also can you elaborate about the 1st part of your question

Comment: What error you get for your 1st question?

Answer (score 0):

To define a variable under MainActivity, you need the following format:

```
contactNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact_names);
```

This will cast it to the ListView type.  Also, verify that contact_names is in the mainactivity layout.

Comment: I tried like you said but have this error -  Unknown class: 'contactNames'  or error: <identifier> expected

Comment: Verify that :   private ListView contactNames;  is in the mainactivity and you have it spelled correctly to match what is in the method.   Can you also post the appropriate part of your mainactivity xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The findViewById() is what links the widgets or controls in the xml to a Java-based object.  Therefore setContentView() has to be executed BEFORE because that is what inflates the view in order to find the resources in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there when you call `findViewById` it get view from from current context and after when you call set setContentView it set your **XML** layout as activity content, so then you can call `findViewById` to get view it is the simple definition of your question's second part.